# Slick with PostgreSQL Scala SBT Intellij IDEA

Tags: postgresql, scala, intellij-idea, slick

I am trying to create a project with Slick in Intellij IDEA with PostgreSQL driver. But I have managed to find only [this tutorial](http://queirozf.com/entries/scala-slick-simple-example-on-connecting-to-a-postgresql-database)
I followed it, but I have got an error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'url'

Here is my code for the main class:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

object Main {

  case class Song(
                   id: Int,
                   name: String,
                   singer: String)

  class SongsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Song](tag, "songs") {
    def id = column[Int]("id")

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def singer = column[String]("singer")

    def * = (id, name, singer) <> (Song.tupled, Song.unapply)
  }

  lazy val songsTable = TableQuery[SongsTable] 
  val db = Database.forConfig("scalaxdb")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val connectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/songs?user=postgres&password=postgresp"

    Database.forURL(connectionUrl, driver = "org.postgresql.Driver") withSession {
      implicit session =>
        val songs = TableQuery[SongsTable]
        songs.list foreach { row =>
          println("song with id " + row.id + " has name " + row.name + " and a singer is " + row.singer)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

These is application.conf file:

```
scalaxdb = {
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  properties = {
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname?user=user&password=password"
  }
}
```

And this is build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I would be very grateful for any advice on fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you mind to use a little more up-to-date version of Slick?

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main {

  case class Song(
                   id: Int,
                   name: String,
                   singer: String)

  class SongsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Song](tag, "songs") {
    def id = column[Int]("id")

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def singer = column[String]("singer")

    def * = (id, name, singer) <> (Song.tupled, Song.unapply)
  }

  val db = Database.forConfig("scalaxdb")

  val songs = TableQuery[SongsTable]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    Await.result({
      db.run(songs.result).map(_.foreach(row =>
        println("song with id " + row.id + " has name " + row.name + " and a singer is " + row.singer)))
    }, 1 minute)
  }
}
```

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.25"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
```